# muliple wordpress multisite installs on the same sever

Tags: multisite, customization, installation

I want a separate production and test/dev instance. Is it possible to have two installs of wordpress multi on the same server, using different databases or do I need 2 servers, one for test and one for production?

I want to have a test instance where I can try out plugins, setting changes etc, without affecting my production instance

Comment: Thanks for the answers. We ended up having two installs on the same server, each pointing at a different database and it has been excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have 2 WP MultiSite installs on the same server - just treat them as 2 separate virtual hosts, put the WP files in separate folders and use separate databases (although you can use the same database server)

Comment: You can even use the same database and just use different prefixes. But I also use different databases, to keep things clear.

Comment: @Jan Fabry - very true, but this makes it harder to dump the particular set of tables for a blog if you need to! So, like you, I tend to create a new database per site

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server, but I see no reason for this not to work. In fact I have the same setup of production and test multisite installations on one server.